# Get a new Image by cropping

Tags: c#, uwp, crop

I'm trying to convert my cropped image (and/or Grid) to new Normal Image , but it returns as it cropped , in same position, how to fix it, there is how works my program after cropping

[image]

```
 private async void Save(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            RenderTargetBitmap renderTargetBitmap = new RenderTargetBitmap();
            await renderTargetBitmap.RenderAsync(GGrid, 4096 , 2448);
           // IBuffer pixels = await renderTargetBitmap.GetPixelsAsync();
            IBuffer pixelBuffer = await renderTargetBitmap.GetPixelsAsync();
            FileSavePicker fileSavePicker = new FileSavePicker();
            fileSavePicker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.PicturesLibrary;
            fileSavePicker.FileTypeChoices.Add("JPEG files", new List<string>() {  ".png"});
            fileSavePicker.SuggestedFileName = "image";

            var outputFile = await fileSavePicker.PickSaveFileAsync();

            if (outputFile == null)
            {
                // The user cancelled the picking operation
                return;
            }
            using (IRandomAccessStream stream = await outputFile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite))
            {

                var encoder = await BitmapEncoder.CreateAsync(BitmapEncoder.PngEncoderId, stream);
                encoder.SetPixelData(
                    BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8,
                    BitmapAlphaMode.Straight,
                    (uint)renderTargetBitmap.PixelWidth,
                    (uint)renderTargetBitmap.PixelHeight,
                    DisplayInformation.GetForCurrentView().LogicalDpi,
                    DisplayInformation.GetForCurrentView().LogicalDpi,
                    pixelBuffer.ToArray());
                try
                {

                    await encoder.FlushAsync();
                }
                catch (Exception err)
                {
                    switch (err.HResult)
                    {
                        case unchecked((int)0x88982F81): //WINCODEC_ERR_UNSUPPORTEDOPERATION
                                                         // If the encoder does not support writing a thumbnail, then try again
                                                         // but disable thumbnail generation.
                            encoder.IsThumbnailGenerated = false;
                            break;
                        default:
                            throw err;
                    }
                }

                //if (encoder.IsThumbnailGenerated == false)
                //{
                //    await encoder.FlushAsync();
                //}


            }
        }
```

Comment: What does the content of `GGrid` look like? Can you post XAML and screenshot?

Comment: I'have already done it, thank you, I just change XAML

Answer (score 0):

[image]

You need to translate and crop the bitmap.

```
double x,y,w,h;

GGrid.RenderTransform = new TranslateTransform
{
    X = -x, // translate back to origin (0,0)
    Y = -y
};

RenderTargetBitmap renderTargetBitmap = new RenderTargetBitmap();
await renderTargetBitmap.RenderAsync(GGrid, w, h); // use crop size
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, actually it doesn't create new image it just change the position , and there still empty space

Comment: What happens when you use a smaller size? `await renderTargetBitmap.RenderAsync(GGrid, 400 , 300);` Do you see less black space?

Comment: I see more black space, it just make Image smaller